# how do i put data only when data is not null

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mybatis

i don't know how to explain this sound and clear but i will try my best.

right now i am setting a asset info update page.

this page includes all the datas including upload function for asset pictures

the problem occurs when, asset with a asset picture is updated without changing the picture,

its profile picture gets replaced with the default image.

right now i am trying to prevent this from happening but i do not know how.

```
<update id="update_hw" parameterType="java.util.Map">
        UPDATE ASSETINFO
        SET assetCode = #{assetCode},
            assetRegGb = #{assetRegGb},
            <choose>
                <when test="autoFlag != null">
                autoFlag = #{autoFlag},
                </when>
            </choose>
            rentalCode = #{rentalCode},
            rentalPrice = #{rentalPrice},
            receiveDate = #{receiveDate},
            rentalRtnDate = #{rentalRtnDate},
            item = #{item},
            <choose>
                <when test="telecom != null">
                    telecom = #{telecom},
                </when>
            </choose>
            <choose>
                <when test="phnNum != null">
                    phnNum = #{phnNum},
                </when>
            </choose>
            maker = #{maker},
            moName = #{moName},
            serial = #{serial},
            spec = #{spec},
            purpose = #{purpose},
            location = #{location},
**          img = #{img},
            originImg = #{originImg},**
            deleteYn = #{deleteYn},
            updateDate = sysdate()
        WHERE assetCode = #{beforeAssetCode}
        AND cpId = #{cpId}
    AND deleteYn = 'N'
    </update>
```

this is my query for updating profile. img and originImg is the name of the profile picture

when the picture is not uploaded, it returns an empty string ""

so i tried

```
            <choose>
                <when tes="img != ''">
                    img = #{img},
                </when>
            </choose>
            <choose>
                <choose>
                <when test="originImg != ''">
                    originImg = #{originImg},
                </when>
            </choose>
            <choose>
```

I tried this thinking that if only when data coming in is not "",  execute the img update statement.
but this did not work...

any help would be appreciated!!

update info without picture being replaced

Comment: Please adapt to the standards of Stackoverflow. The question needs a [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and also check on [How to ask a Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

```
        <choose>
            <when test="img != null">
                img = #{img},
                originImg = #{originImg},
            </when>
        </choose>
```

well... this worked for me...

Comment: your question in generailized. be more specific to get excat answer.